# Как изменить инлайн клавиатуру telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Использую inline клавиатуру хочу сделать так чтобы, после нажатия кнопки сообщение и клавиатура изменялась в зависимости от выбранной кнопки.
Приложил фотографию как сейчас всё работает. То есть всё оставить также, только избавится от нового сообщения и сделать инлайн клавиатуру в одном сообщении!
Видел команду edit_message_reply_markup, но так и не понял как с ней разобраться, вот код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
elif (call.data == 'menu'):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    b1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Магазины', callback_data='magazin')
    b2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Оставить отзыв⭐', callback_data='otziv')
    b3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Поддержка⚙', callback_data='podderzhka')
    b4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Инструкция', callback_data='instrukciya')

    keyboard.add(b1)
    keyboard.add(b2)
    keyboard.add(b3)
    keyboard.add(b4)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                     f"...",
                     reply_markup=keyboard)
elif (call.data == 'magazin'):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    b1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Одежда и обувь", callback_data='o')
    b2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кино", callback_data='k')
    b3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Доставка", callback_data='d')
    b4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Маркетплейсы", callback_data='m')
    b5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Такси", callback_data='t')
    b6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Музыка", callback_data='mu')
    b7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Хобби", callback_data='hob')
    b8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Электроника⚡", callback_data='elec')
    b9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Спорттовары⚽", callback_data='sport')
    b10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Аптека", callback_data='apt')
    b11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Красота", callback_data='kra')
    b12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Цветы", callback_data='cvety')
    b13 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Детские товары", callback_data='det')
    keyboard.add(b1)
    keyboard.add(b2)
    keyboard.add(b3)
    keyboard.add(b4)
    keyboard.add(b5)
    keyboard.add(b6)
    keyboard.add(b7)
    keyboard.add(b8)
    keyboard.add(b9)
    keyboard.add(b10)
    keyboard.add(b11)
    keyboard.add(b12)
    keyboard.add(b13)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                     text="Выберите категорию промокодов:\n",
                     reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `bot.send_message` делаешь так

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(msg: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 1", callback_data="but_1"))
    bot.send_message(chat_id=msg.chat.id, text="Жми кнопку", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "but_1")
def but1_pressed(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 2", callback_data="but_2"))
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, reply_markup=markup)
```

PS.
А еще не стоит просто так брать условие в скобки `(call.data == 'magazin')` это не имеет никакого смысла, и мешает нормально воспринимать код

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но я решил проблему, используя структуру edit_message_text в последней строчке кода